# Visual Studio 2008 setup for SSRS development on AX 2009

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

My problem is that I didn't find how to develop outside production environment, I mean when I deploy my dynamics AX reporting projects, I find them in my AX production environment, is there a way to specify deployment target (dev, test or other)? I tried to add /AxConfig switch to Visual Studio Shortcut with path to AX config files for different environment but I have an error message from Visual Studio: Invalid Command Line. Unknown Switch : AxConfig.

I'm using AX 2009 no SP1, SQL Server 2005, Visual Studio 2008, reports are working fine in Visual Studio and AX.

Answer (score 0):

Just change it in the project properties

[image: Project Properties]

Change these settings

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't have the same window properties as your screenshot, I don't have the settings you're showing